# How to use the Hibernate with Camel?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, apache-camel

I found couple of guidelines to implement JPA using hibernate but nither of resources provided complete guide. Following are couple of resources I used but not able to success.

[Camel official web page](http://camel.apache.org/hibernate-example.html), But I could not able to find the relavent source. I check there [official repository](https://github.com/apache/camel) there is no such project available.

Most of examples does not contain code sample which we can run and understand the process. Can please some experienced person provide good reading material to understand the way which I can used hibernate with camel.

Please note that I'm quite new to camel and still on early stages in learning this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help] and take the [tour] to learn what questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow. As asked, your question is off-topic since it is asking for [off-site resources](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The question is what is your usecase? Camel itself has support Hibernate in more than one way: https://camel.apache.org/jpa.html and https://camel.apache.org/hibernate.html